# how to add uiview as a subview to existing view

Tags: iphone

I want to add a `UIView` of smaller frame as subview to parental view but I am not getting the needed.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:something];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Can anyone suggest me the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are adding a blank view to another view.  Maybe you don't see it because it is blank?

What is "something"?

Comment: i am giving a frame in place of something

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view`? It might be that you're adding this subview somewhere in the view hierarchy where it's obscured.  In your code fragment there, you would add:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:view];
```

Of course, without supplying more code (preferably directly from your project, and which actually compiles), I'm just guessing.  What were you expecting to happen?  What actually happened?